# session timeout only for current request

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I was wondering about something , in my website which depends totally on wcf services . When the user keeps the website open for a longtime and then clicks any button , the service sees his asp.net session as null , though if he refreshes the page everything goes back to normal , is there any property in session state or something to make the site working all the time even if the user is idle ??

Answer (score 0):

Your session would be expiring after a interval configured in web.config. Change the timeout in SessionState tag to 60 in web.config now it will expire after one hour. Read about session state for info [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="60"/>
```

Comment: This timeout is set to the max 1440 minutes , and the session remains it doesnt expire , refreshing the page already gets the user back .

Comment: If you are getting unexpected session termination check the code if you are assigning null to some required session key. We had a similar situation the session was getting null on one page which was required on other page which might be visited direct or indirectly from the page which make session null by mistake

Comment: Its the currentmember being null in session , it's almost impossible to make it null else by log out page.